# Port Redirect on Mac

Tags: php, macos, port, portforwarding

What is the easiest option to redirect a request to a different host/port?

Here is my entire scenario:
I am making a request using php to a certain ip and port. The response includes another url location, but it is badly configured and instead of including ip and port, it simply includes a server name. Now, if I access the entire url location that I have as response with the server name replaced with the proper ip and port it works.
I've tried editing /etc/hosts setting the server name to the ip address, but how do I workaround the port too?

I am using mac osx 10.9.4, and I've tried some things with ipfw and pf, but neither really worked.

Thanks.

Comment: You could maybe hack something together with `netcat` (a.k.a `nc`) that sits in a loop listening locally and you make your request to that. It then asks the "badly configured server" on your behalf and edits in the the port number and replies with the correct server and port... ugly but could maybe work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem quite recently on Mavericks (10.9). The way I solved it included 2 steps:

1. **hosts file**

   Simply added a line similar to this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 www.someaddress.com
   ```
2. **port forwarding**

   To set up port forwarding I used ipfw, which worked fine, e.g:

   ```
   ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,9001 tcp from any to any 80 in
   ```

   In the example above port 9001 is forwarded to port 80. Even though ipfw is deprecated it still works.

Comment: it didn't work. the hosts had an effect, but the ipfw didn't. any idea why?

Comment: You can check if running ipfw command actually set the rule by running `ipfw list` (may need sudo) - this will give the full list of applied port forwarding rules.

Comment: In my case I also needed to make sure that I set port forwarding **first** and only afterwards start my server application which relies on it. Other point to remember: every time you reboot your machine, you need to set port forwarding again.